# How do I migrate a SandBox solution into a SharePoint App?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sandbox-solution

Microsoft appears to be removing code-based sandbox solutions in SharePoint online.

I have been using an on-premise SharePoint Enterprise solution since 2012 that included a code-based .wsp sandbox solution  that shows SharePoint Version in Office Documents, available for free at CodePlex.

As such, can anybody recommend a path for me having the existing .wsp solution converted to a SharePoint online add-in/app, please? I am not a developer so wouldn't know where to start, who to approach or whether this is even possible.

Many thanks,

Comment: am also facing the same issue so here I started developing apps for web parts which was developed in sandbox solutions and i dont think you can  convert any sandbox .wsp/solution to the apps beacuse in Apps the entire logic is written in javascript.

Comment: as it is my opinion am not saying that there wouldn't be such procedure

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct option to convert **SandBox** `.wsp` in **App**. It will be a complete renewal. The **API**s you have used in **SandBox** solutions are also available in SharePoint **App**. There are two types of **App** in SharePoint like

1. **SharePoint Hosted App**. You have to develop it using **JSOM** or REST **API**.
2. **Provider Hosted App**. You can use **CSOM** here.

So start writing App which one suits you best and ask here again if you are unable to find any equivalent API of your **SandBox** solution in **JSOM**, **REST API** or **CSOM**. You will find several tutorials in web for developing SharePoint Apps and that's why I am not providing any reference here.

Comment: It is not completely true that APIs used in Sandbox are available to Add-in model. Mostly yes, but not always 1:1. Some aren't available in CSMO, but it has improved especially about SharePoint Online. It really depends on what your Sandbox solution consists of

Comment: The source code for the sandbox solution can be found here: https://spversionindocs.codeplex.com/releases/view/52950, can anybody determine whether this can be used in an add-in model please? Many thanks, Phil